# Disable whitelisted permission will affect to the pre installed application or not?

Tags: android, permissions, location, android-permissions

I am just curious to know, if we are using whitelisted permission in our application. Whitelisted permission are granted by OEM. Let’s take an example of location permission in a System app, which is by default enabled. Suppose user is going to settings and disable the permission.

> Will it really affect to the app? Will the system app stop collecting
> the location data after denying the location permission? or it won’t t
> affect to the system app because already whitelisted by OEM?

Answer (score 0):

Here is official documentation: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/perms-whitelist

And it says:

> Historically, device manufacturers had little control over which signature|privileged permissions could be granted to privileged apps.
>
> Starting in **Android 8.0**, manufacturers must explicitly grant privileged permissions in the system configuration XML files in the /etc/permissions directory.
>
> As of **Android 9**, implementors must explicitly grant or deny all
> privileged permissions or the device won’t boot.

Also:

> Only permissions defined by the core platform (the "android" package) must be whitelisted. **Privileged permissions defined by device manufacturers will still be automatically granted.**

So standard android privileges (example: `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`) can be disabled, but custom vendor privileges (example: `com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_LOCATION`) are automatically granted.

PS: I highly recommend checking everything yourself on a real device. Android documentation is not always correct. And I personally have never worked with a whitelist permission, so I can't say anything besides quoting documentation.